# Where can I find ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit compatible drivers for my Lenovo IP 310 6th gen Core i3 machine?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, ideapad

Hey there computer hackers,

Greetings!

I am a nOOb here. I am a newbie to Linux as well. I haven't deployed it yet.
Now, I have a Lenovo IP 310 6th gen core i3 machine. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit as it's primary host OS. I don't know where to find these following drivers, which pieces I think are essential for running this machine, perfectly.
I need Ubuntu compatible drivers for,

1. AMDVGA
2. Camera_RealtekDSP
3. CardReader
4. Chipset
5. Hd Graphics
6. IME
7. Intel Dual band Bluetooth
8. Intel Dual band Wifi
9. IRST
10. LenovoUtility
11. Realtech Lan
12. Touchpad Lenovo Pointing

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Shuvo

Comment: Use a new kernel, and everything should work out of the box without any extra tinkering. You may have problems with the WiFi, but that's unlikely.

Comment: Give it a trial run by booting the Ubuntu Live 16.10 DVD/USB. See what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Everything's likely to just work after a Ubuntu 16 install.

Software updater supports many hardware, and you can find some extra propietary ones under "Additional drivers" (an app that comes with Ubuntu).

Your manufacturer might also have some Linux drivers in their official page. You can also query your hardware manufacturers one by one to see if they have got any specific proprietary (or not) drivers published on their pages.